# How to running code on PyCharm with 2nd file

Tags: debugging, pycharm

Hello I a a beginner to Python and thus PyCharm.
I keep trying too run a new file but can't get it to work.

[image]

I have attached a picture for reference. I have the 2 files open at the top as you can see (Blue) however if I click run on the second file it just runs the first, this seems to happen even if I close the first file. I thought maybe I had to change the config (pink) but I don't know what I am doing and I then usually get an error saying cannot find or something like that.
Is there a standard way to config a new file so it doesn't mess up?
Is  my assumption to the problem correct?

Comment: The image that you have posted is of very low quality. Can you post a clearer image.

Comment: Right click within the file and choose "Run": https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-without-any-previous-configuring.html